# MYSQL Moving Average calculation with precedence unbounded

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, subquery

I have a table with three columns : id, A, B. I would like to populate a column E with the calculations below.

** Cols C and D are non-existent in my table, they are subqueries that i hope to create and put into my query that will help me populate col E. As it seems,C and D is a moving average but there is not much examples around that can help with that.

```
Table followers
 id    A   B      C                                  D                     E
  _    _   _      _                                  _                     _

  0    1   2  A0/(AVG(A0))  #1/1                B0/(AVG(B0))            (C0+D0)/2
  1    2   2  A1/(AVG(A1,A0)) #2/((2+1)/2)      B1/(AVG(B1,B0))         (C1+D1)/2
  2    3   2  A2/(AVG(A1,A2,A0)) #3/((3+2+1)/3) B2/(AVG(B1,B2,B0))      (C2+D2)/2
```

How can i write a query for this? I believe i will need a left outer join to itself.

I was thinking set the calculations for column C as one variable, calculations for column D as another variable.

So for column C this is my approach:

```
update followers f left outer join
       followers f2...
```

Not sure how to continue as i dont know how i can do

```
 f.id=f2.id where f2.id between f.id and f2.id+1.
```

I got some help to use this query but it didnt work:

```
UPDATE 
    f,
    (
        SELECT AVG(f.A) 
        FROM (
            SELECT f.A  
            FROM f 
            WHERE f.id <= f.id
        ) as t 
    ) as temp,
    (
        SELECT AVG(f.B) 
        FROM (
            SELECT f.B  
            FROM f 
            WHERE f.id <= f.id
        ) as t2 
    ) as temp2
SET 
    f.C =((f.A/temp) + (f.B/temp2))/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use subqueries for this

```
SELECT id, A, B, C, D, (C+D)/2 E FROM (
    SELECT id, A, B,
    (A/(SELECT AVG(A) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id)) C,
    (B/(SELECT AVG(B) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id)) D
    FROM table t1 ) t3
```

This query assumes that AVG(A) and AVG(B) are always > 0. If that's not true you'll need to use `CASE` so you don't end up dividing by 0.

Another version using JOIN, probably faster than using subqueries

```
SELECT t3.id, t3.A, t3.B, 
(t3.A/t4.AVG_A) C, (t3.B/t4.AVG_B) D,
((t3.A/t4.AVG_A) + (t3.B/t4.AVG_B))/2 E
FROM table t3
JOIN (SELECT t1.id, AVG(t2.A) AVG_A, AVG(t2.B) AVG_B
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t2.id <= t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id) t4 ON t3.id = t4.id
```

Comment: for your first query, i assume you are just populating column E? and do i need a join for the first query since there are multiple tables?

Comment: @jenn both queries populate all columns. a join isn't needed for the 1st query because subqueries are used to access t2

Comment: I already have the id, col A and col B. I do not need col C or D. I just need to populate E given the numbers from id, A and B. Will this query work for that? I just put C and D in there for easier reference but those cols do not exist.

Comment: @jenn yes it should work, if you don't need c and d then omit from your select statement

Comment: If i am just updating column E, should i add `update f SET col E= SELECT...` where f is the table name.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using variables.

```
select t.id, t.A, t.B,
       (case when (@n := @n + 1) is null then null
             when (@c := @c + a) is null then null
             else t.A / (@c / @n)
        end) as C,
       (case when (@d := @d + b) is null then null
             else t.B / (@d / @n)
        end) as D,
       (t.A / (@c / @n)) + (t.B / (@d / @n)) as E
from table t cross join
     (select @c := 0, @d := 0, @n := 1) vars
order by id;
```

You can put this in an update statement using a `join`.

```
update table t join
   (select t.id, t.A, t.B,
           (case when (@n := @n + 1) is null then null
                 when (@c := @c + a) is null then null
                 else t.A / (@c / @n)
            end) as C,
           (case when (@d := @d + b) is null then null
                 else t.B / (@d / @n)
            end) as D,
           (t.A / (@c / @n)) + (t.B / (@d / @n)) as E
    from table t cross join
         (select @c := 0, @d := 0, @e := 0, @n := 1) vars
    order by id
   ) newvals
   on t.id = newvals.id
set t.C = newvals.C,
    t.D = newvals.D,
    t.E = newvals.E;
```

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate more on how this could fit into an update statement with a join. Would t be the second table if f is my original table?

Comment: I get NULL for all rows in my col E which shouldn't be the case

Comment: @jenn . . . If the subquery works, then it should be assigning the same values into the table.  But you will get `NULL` values if any of the columns contain `NULL` values.

Comment: how do i ignore NULL values?

Comment: @jenn . . . Either add `where A is not null and B is not null` to the subquery or use `coalesce()` in the calculations so they are treated as `0`.  It depends what you want to do with them.